# Define a enum data types for use in several files

Tags: c, types, enums

I have several files like
main.c, main.h, some_funcs.c and some_funcs.h.

```
main.h is included in main.c
main.h include some_funcs.h
some_funcs.c include some_funcs.h
```

When I now define a new data type like:

```
//Datatypes
enum _bool {
   false = 0,
   true = 1
};

typedef enum _bool Bool;
```

If i define it in e.g. main.h and want to use it in some_func.c it does not work. Is there a ways to define it somewhere without always include the header where it is defined?

Comment: In C99, the type `_Bool` was added, and the header `<stdbool.h>`, containing the macros `true`, `false`, and `#define bool _Bool`. (Just for this particular case, that doesn't answer the general question.)

Comment: And a note, identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in the tag name space at file scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the definition in `some_funcs.h`. This will make it visible in main.h, main.c, some_funcs.h and some_funcs.c.

A more general solution is to put common data types into a file named `common.h` for instance.

You then include this file in all header files.

This would be the content of the `common.h` file. The `ifdef` is to ignore the content of the file if it was already included.

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

//Datatypes
enum _bool {
   false = 0,
   true = 1
};

typedef enum _bool Bool;

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a ways to define it somewhere without always include the header where it is defined?

NO.

You have to include header in each source file.

A normal practice is to have your own  `typdef.h`. Define your own data types in it and include it in your source files of interest.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a ways to define it somewhere without always include the
>   header where it is defined?

It sounds like can I use a definition of a type without defining it.:)

You should include the header file where the enumeration and typedef are defined in each module that uses it.

Take into account that there is 1) type `_Bool` in C and 2) standard header `<stdbool.h>` where macros `bool`, `false`, and `true` are already defined.